# embed ios8 share sheet into a frame?

Tags: ios, ios8, sharing

Is it possible to present the standard IOS8 share sheet on a page while also showing other content on that page?  We want to have a few other sharing options that are more customized along with a view of the standard share sheet but ideally we don't want the share sheet options to require an additional action (and a window popping up over the other stuff) - we just want everything to appear at once.  Possible?

Comment: Ron, you can customize the UIActivityViewController to suit your needs. For example, you can omit specific share options, say you don't want Facebook to populate etc. However, if your trying to show alternatives behind the UIActivityController on the main view, while the UIActivityController is displayed you might have a hard time, the UIActivityController becomes the firstResponder as soon as it displays

Answer (score 0):

technically.. yes. you could mess with the view structure and modify it to your heartss desire

BUT that would be a nogo if you want to target the App Store

---

note: I am assuming here that you don't want to just modify the controller as specified by the docs. thats of course possible ;)